# How to get know index of the area clicked in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a chart which not necessarily have element at a specified index, but I want to know the index of the area which is clicked.

[image]

If I hover on an area which don't have an element it shows me the tooltip assigned to the area. I just need the same with click and get the index of the area.

Answer (score 3):

In chart js options you can have onClick event , you can read here [ChartJS onClick](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html).

Using the onClick you will the get the event and you can check the below code to get the index.

Addition to it the x and y value are also logged.

i hope the below code will solve your issue.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 20, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    onClick: function(c,i){
     e = i[0];
    console.log("index",e._index)
    var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
    var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
    console.log("x value",x_value);
    console.log("y value",y_value);
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 80
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```